# rails, sqlite, TypeError: can't cast Array to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Books#index
>
> TypeError: can't cast Array to string: INSERT INTO "amazonitems"
>   ("asin", "author", "created_at", "detailpageurl", "isbn",
>   "l_image_url", "m_image_url", "manufacturer", "product_group",
>   "publication_date", "s_image_url", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

application_helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def get_amazon_item_data(asin)
    rec = Amazonitem.where(asin: "#{asin}").first
    if !rec or rec.updated_at < DateTime.now - 0.5
      unless rec
        rec = Amazonitem.new() unless rec
        rec.asin = asin
      end

      amazon_res = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, response_group: 'Medium')

      if amazon_res and amazon_res.first_item
        item = amazon_res.first_item
        element = item.get_element('ItemAttributes')
        rec.detailpageurl = item.get('DetailPageURL'),
        rec.isbn = element.get("ISBN"),
        rec.title = element.get("Title"),
        rec.author = element.get_array("Author").join(","),
        rec.manufacturer = element.get("Manufacturer"),
        rec.product_group = element.get("ProductGroup"),
        rec.publication_date = element.get("PublicationDate"),
        rec.s_image_url = item.get("SmallImage/URL"),
        rec.m_image_url = item.get("MediumImage/URL"),
        rec.l_image_url = item.get("LargeImage/URL")
      else
        rec.detailpageurl = nil
      end
      rec.updated_at = DateTime.now
      rec.save
    end
    return rec
  end
end
```

I can't save into sqlite db. help me.

Comment: I suppose thate are no evaluation for (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) string, and all parameters were stored as an array. Please check the evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of `rec` attributes is an array. Try adding (temporarily):

```
raise Hash[rec.attributes.select {|_,v| v.is_a? Array}].inspect
```

just before saving and correct given attributes assignment - db is expecting a string.

Also Do not touch `updated_at` column - it will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

use to_s to prevent this type of error. for example, in my application i was getting error because of this code -

```
   Urllist.create(
     :url => @abc,
     :success => @success,
     :failed => @failed,
     :failedemail => @faillikearray
   )
```

here `@faillikearray` was an array. my problem was fixed using this -

```
   Urllist.create(
     :url => @abc,
     :success => @success,
     :failed => @failed,
     :failedemail => @faillikearray.to_s
   )
```